# Can my employer make me wear a jumper?

Tags: uniforms

My manager says we are getting jumpers that we have to wear while the shops is open.  Can they make me even if I'm hot?

Comment: For those who might not be aware, "jumper" is the UK term for what's called a "sweater" in the US.

http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27568/whats-the-difference-between-a-jumper-a-pullover-and-a-sweater

Comment: Not if you are working for a James Bond villain. In that case, everyone must wear the same blue / gold / black / etc jumpsuit and the beret as well, sorry.

Answer (score 14):

Generally speaking (because we don't give legal advice and you did not mention your jurisdiction) yes, your company can make your wear their dress. I know countries where that means they have to pay for your dress, but I don't know any country where you would get away with not wearing the dress your company wants you to wear.

If it's very hot and the jumper is hindering you in doing your job most efficiently, talk to the other employees how they cope and if most of them have this problem, talk to your manager and suggest an alternative (wear company shirts instead maybe).

If it's so hot it's threatening your health, talk to your doctor and then to your manager. That might be a valid reason to have a different kind of company dress.

Comment: or ask your manager to install a fan, you have more chance of that then getting excused from wearing the uniform.

Comment: Most countries have regulations on thermal stress as a work safety issue. However the fact that in summer it would be more comfortable to wear shorts where office workers usually wear suits (for example) can't be seen as a health risk.

Comment: Why would talking to your dr be silly if its threatning your health?  Im not sure where you're from but there are places that heat is much more dangerous then cold.  I would assume that if they are requiring sweaters they are probably not in an extremelly hot climate but it is still worth mentioning.

Comment: @dbanet I would hope that in most jurisdictions a letter from a physician that states nvoigt should not wear a jumper for health reasons would have the effect of relieving nvoigt from the obligation of wearing a jumper.